# What is the type for dereferencing an iterator to a map or some other composite types in C++

Tags: c++, stl

My question is what is the type for `*it`, if `it` is of the type of `std::map<std::string, int>::iterator`

As a follow up to that question, if I would like to use accumulate to calculate all the map values, how could I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's a reference to an `std::pair<const KeyT, ValueT>` (where `KeyT` and `ValueT` are the key and value parameters of the map). You may write some kind of iterator wrapper to wrap map iterators, make them return just the value and then use `std::accumulate`:

```
template<typename ItT>
struct SecondIterator
{
    ItT it;

    SecondIterator(const ItT &it) : it(it) {}

    SecondIterator &operator++()
    {
        ++it;
        return *this;
    }

    SecondIterator operator++(int)
    {
        SecondIterator t=*this;
        ++(*this);
        return t;
    }

    SecondIterator &operator--()
    {
        --it;
        return *this;
    }

    SecondIterator operator--(int)
    {
        SecondIterator t=*this;
        --(*this);
        return t;
    }

    typename ItT::value_type::second_type &operator*()
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    bool operator==(const SecondIterator &other)
    {
        return it==other.it;
    }

    bool operator!=(const SecondIterator &other)
    {
        return it!=other.it;
    }

};
```

(probably I forgot some `typename` here and there, but you got the idea)

but if you ask me it's definitely not worth the effort.

Comment: it actually returns a _reference_ to an `std::pair<KeyT, ValueT>`.

Comment: it's `const KeyT`, keys are immutable

Comment: Possibly relevant member typedefs: `std::map<K, V>::key_type`, `std::map<K, V>::mapped_type` (just the value), `std::map<K, V>::value_type` (the pair, same as `std::map<K, V>::iterator::value_type`), `std::pair<F, S>::first_type`, `std::pair<F, S>::second_type`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accumulate the `mapped_type` of a `std::map`, perhaps the following helper classes will be of interest:

```
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>

#ifndef USE_CXX11
#if (__cplusplus >= 201100) || (_MSC_VER >= 1800)
#define USE_CXX11 1
#endif
#endif

#if USE_CXX11
/*
    map_value_accumulator - helper class that allows iterators of std::map 
    to be used with std::accumulate
*/
template <typename T, typename Op = std::plus<typename T::mapped_type> >
class map_value_accumulator
{
public:
    typedef typename T::value_type pair_type;
    typedef typename T::mapped_type value_type;

    value_type operator()( value_type acc, pair_type const& p) const {
        return op_( acc, p.second);
    }

    map_value_accumulator() : op_(Op()) {};
    map_value_accumulator(Op&& op) : op_(op) {};

private:
    Op op_;        
};

/*
    make_map_value_accumulator() - function that uses argument deduction to
        help create map_value_accumulator objects
*/

// make_map_value_accumulator() that returns a user-specified operation
//  the operation defaults to std::plus<> is not specified
template <typename T, typename Op = std::plus<typename T::mapped_type> >
map_value_accumulator< T, Op>
make_map_value_accumulator( T const& m, Op&& op = Op())
{
    return map_value_accumulator< T, Op>(std::forward<Op>(op));
}
#else
/*
    map_value_accumulator - helper class that allows iterators of std::map 
    to be used with std::accumulate
*/
template <typename T, typename Op = std::plus<typename T::mapped_type> >
class map_value_accumulator
{
public:
    typedef typename T::value_type pair_type;
    typedef typename T::mapped_type value_type;
    typedef std::plus<typename T::mapped_type> default_operator_type;

    value_type operator()( value_type acc, pair_type const& p) const {
        return op_( acc, p.second);
    }

    map_value_accumulator() : op_(default_operator_type()) {};
    map_value_accumulator(Op op) : op_(op) {};

private:
    Op op_;        
};
/*
    make_map_value_accumulator() - function that uses argument deduction to
        help create map_value_accumulator objects
*/
template <typename T, typename Op>
map_value_accumulator< T, Op>
make_map_value_accumulator( T const& m, Op const& op)
{
    return map_value_accumulator< T, Op>(op);
}

template <typename T>
map_value_accumulator< T, std::plus<typename T::mapped_type> >
make_map_value_accumulator( T const& m)
{
    typedef std::plus<typename T::mapped_type> default_operator_type;

    return map_value_accumulator< T, default_operator_type>();
}
#endif /* USE_CXX11 */



#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<char, int> m;

    m.insert(std::make_pair('a', 1));
    m.insert(std::make_pair('z', 26));
    m.insert(std::make_pair('c', 3));
    m.insert(std::make_pair('b', 2));
    m.insert(std::make_pair('?', -2));

    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    // directly create the map_value_accumulator functor (defaults to std::plus)
    cout << accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 0,  map_value_accumulator<std::map<char,int> >()) << endl;

    // create a map_value_accumulator deduced from the user's map type (default to std::plus)
    cout << accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 0,  make_map_value_accumulator(m)) << endl;

    // create a map_value_accumulator deduced from the user's map type and specifying an operation functor
    cout << accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 1,  make_map_value_accumulator(m, std::multiplies<int>())) << endl;

#if USE_CXX11
    cout << "accumulate with a lambda: ";
    // create a map_value_accumulator deduced from the user's map type and specifying a lambda for the operation
    //  (will perform a sum of squares)
    cout << accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 0,  make_map_value_accumulator(m, [](int x, int y){ return x + y * y; })) << endl;
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I've updated the example. The first example would not work with lambdas and didn't work with MS compilers older than VS 2013.  The new example has some conditional compilation that has a C++11 implementation (that supports lambdas) and a non-C++11 variant that works with VS 2003 and later and presumably any reasonable version of GCC.